# How to manipulate a constructor parameter before both assigning it to a final variable and passing it to a super constructor?

Tags: dart

Consider this code:

```dart
class Parent {
  final List<int> bytes;
  Parent(this.bytes);
}

class Child extends Parent {
  final String name;
  
  Child(String s) : name = s.trim(), super(s.trim().codeUnits);
}
```

Basically, `Child` accepts a `String` as constructor parameter. What I want to do is to trim it, store it in the `name` variable and also pass its `codeUnits` to the `super` constructor. The problem I'm facing is that it seems there is no way to avoid calling `trim` twice. I would love to use `name` inside `super`, but Dart doesn't let me. Is there some work around to have `trim` only called once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to make a second constructor that prepares the data before using your real constructor (now marked private):

```dart
class Child extends Parent {
  final String name;

  Child._(this.name) : super(name.codeUnits);
  Child(String s) : this._(s.trim());
}
```

If you have a more complicated case, you could also consider using a factory constructor:
https://dart.dev/language/constructors#factory-constructors

Comment: It's unfortunate that in my actual use case I have a bunch of parameters, and this solution requires me to write quite a bit of boiler plate code, but it works as intended. Thanks. Given that I don't have to do much work inside the constructor, should I prefer this solution over factory constructors, or it is irrelevant?

Comment: My guess is that it is going to be irrelevant what kind of constructor you end up using. I am sure there are some minor performance differences but since you are doing this to preventing some kind of expensive calculations, the overhead of the choice of constructor are going to be not relevant.